# Node.js res.send VS res.end VS return res.end

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have the following code that has a syntax error in the mongodb findAndUpdateOne update query.

```
router.post('/buylicense', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.cid) {
        return res.send('failed');
    }
    Company.findOne({
        ownedBy: req.user.local.username,
        _id: req.body.cid
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send('failed');
        }
        if (result.license) {
            return res.send('valid');
        } else {
            Company.findOneAndUpdate({
                ownedBy: req.user.local.username,
                _id: req.body.cid
            }, {
                license: true,
                licenseExpireDate: {
                    $add: ["$date", 3 * 24 * 60 * 60000] // bad code, a problem for another day
                }
            }, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return res.end('failed'); // Code should stop here.
                }
                console.log('got here');
                return res.send('success');
            });
        }
    });
    console.log('How did I get here?');
    res.send('failed');
});
```

My question is why is the code reaching the last part of the code:

```
 console.log('How did I get here?');
 res.send('failed');
```

If I use anything other than `return res.end` the code reaches the end and crashes my app. Simply doing `res.end` does not work, neither does `return res.send`. Should not `return` or at least `res.end` be enough to actually stop the code from reaching the end?

Error displayed if I don't stop the error the `right way`, probably not relevant but here it is:

```
How did I get here?
{ CastError: Cast to date failed for value "[object Object]" at path "licenseExpireDate"
    at MongooseError.CastError (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:19:11)
    at SchemaDate.cast (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/date.js:242:9)
    at SchemaDate.castForQuery (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/date.js:276:17)
    at Query._castUpdateVal (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2477:17)
    at Query._walkUpdatePath (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2372:25)
    at Query._castUpdate (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2296:23)
    at castDoc (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2500:18)
    at Query._findAndModify (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1755:17)
    at Query._findOneAndUpdate (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1622:8)
    at /media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:156:8
    at args (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:71:20)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:728:7)
    at next (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:82:14)
    at Kareem.execPre (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:99:3)
    at Kareem.wrap (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:146:8)
    at Query._findOneAndUpdate (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:188:11)
  message: 'Cast to date failed for value "[object Object]" at path "licenseExpireDate"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'date',
  value: { '$add': [ '$date', 259200000 ] },
  path: 'licenseExpireDate',
  reason: undefined }
got here
_http_outgoing.js:346
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/media/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/media/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at /media/sf_vShared/xyz/app/modalRoutes.js:461:28
    at /media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:160:11
    at Query._findAndModify (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1767:14)
    at Query._findOneAndUpdate (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1622:8)
    at /media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:156:8
    at args (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:71:20)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:728:7)
    at next (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:82:14)
    at Kareem.execPre (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:99:3)
    at Kareem.wrap (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:146:8)
    at Query._findOneAndUpdate (/media/node_modules/kareem/index.js:188:11)
    at Query.findOneAndUpdate (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1611:15)
    at Function.Model.findOneAndUpdate (/media/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1491:13)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Mongoose's find functions are asynchronous, that means they run separately from the main thread and in the background. The code after the call to `Company.findOne`, runs immediately after, you shouldn't res.end/send there. Instead do that on the callback as you already did.

Comment: So for any mongoose operation the way to stop the whole code from continuing is with `return res.end` or is there a better way ?

Comment: return ends any function, this isn't something special for express or mongoose. `res.send` and `end` are express functions to return data for the client.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First let's see what is the difference between three ExpressJS functions

**res.end:** comes from NodeJS core. In Express JS if you need to end request in a quick way and do not need to send any data then you can use this function

**res.send:** Sends data and end the request

**res.json** Sends data in JSON format and ends the request.

> My question is why is the code reaching the last part of the code:?

I hope you know that JavaScript is asynchronous language. All database calls to MongoDB using Mongoose is asynchronous. So `Compnay.findOne` is an asynchronous function call and It stays in event loop until database read operation is not finished. As asynchronous behavior of JS, JS Main thread execution won't wait for the DB function result to return ( no-blocking) and reach the last lines and as your req ends with calling `res.end("failed")` But when DB read operation finished returns data then you again calling `res.send` and you ended with `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Trax `return res.send()` and `return res.end()` should have same effect. But I prefer to go with documentation :-)

Comment: That kinda was my question, why don't the two have the same effect.

Comment: Adding to the answer above, Node's asynchronous nature can cause a situation in which additional lines of code past the `res.send()` function are executed even if promises are not used.